# throws error when tried to compare two arrays of type Object

Tags: selenium

I have come across assertArrayEquals which compares two arrays of type Object.

for eg my array assertion lokos like this

assertArrayEquals( actualVal.get(i) ,expectedVal.get(i));

It throws error "The method assertArrayEquals(Object[], Object[]) in the type Assert is not applicable for the arguments (Object, Object)"

Please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it does not compile, not throw an error. You need to pass an entire array to that method, because that it what it expects.

Comment: like can u give me an example please

Comment: For example, if you wanted to check that all the elements in two arrays `A` and `B` are equal to each other, then you would pass them to the method as follows: `assertArrayEquals(A,B)`.

Comment: i game similar to that could you please recheck my question

Comment: I read your question. What is `actualVal`? I'm guessing it's an array. Then `actualVal.get(i)` is one of the array's elements. The `assertArrayEquals` method wants you to pass it an array, not one of the elements in the array.